# Converting time into an integer on SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-conversion, date-conversion

I am trying to calculate the average of ride_length (hh:mm:ss format) on Big Query.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D11OT.png)
For example, I am aiming for a result that says 1 instead of 01:00:00.

I tried using the CAST function to convert it into an integer but it didn't work. I also tried following the steps of answers to questions similar to mine but they didn't work as well.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how.

Comment: Hi @Michael Karanikolas, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#extract)
function which will return the specified part of the time expressions. You can try the below queries.

To extract hour from the TIME expression you can consider the below query.

**Query:**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIME "01:00:00") as hour;
```

**Output:**

[image]

To extract hour from TIMESTAMP expression below query can be considered.

**Query:**

```
select EXTRACT(hour from timestamp "2023-01-13 15:30:00" AT TIME ZONE "America/Los_Angeles") as hour
```

**Output:**

[image]

To extract hour from the TIME column you can consider the below sample query.

**Query:**

```
SELECT time,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (time)) AS hour from `bigquery-public-data.austin_incidents.incidents_2008` limit 10
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ShipraSarkar. I tried however, the ride_length column has about 50000 different time values. I tried replacing "01:00:00" with "ride_length" in the first query you wrote but I got an error message saying "Invalid TIME literal"